# Selecting a random string from a plist and displaying it in a text field

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsarray, plist, arc4random

Hey I'm very new to iPhone programming and I have been searching for hours both on this site and on google for the solution to my problem. Basically I am trying to make an app which selects a random string out of my plist and displays it into a text field. I have tried countless ways, but this way seems to work the best, however it still crashes when I press a button and gives me the error "EXC_ARITHMETIC" on the arc4random line. As well as this error, the NSLog(@"items: &@", items) displays items: (null) in the log when i press the button. Any help or suggestions are GREATLY appreciated.
P.S. items is an NSMutableArray I already set up in the .h file

```
-(IBAction)buttonPress {
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ItemList" ofType:@"plist"];
    items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"items: %@", items);
    NSInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [items count];
    NSString* randomString = [items objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
    textField.text = randomString;
}
```

Here's the plist code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Array</key>
<array>
    <string>AAA</string>
    <string>BBB</string>
    <string>CCC</string>
    <string>DDD</string>
    <string>EEE</string>
    <string>FFF</string>
    <string>GGG</string>
    <string>HHH</string>
    <string>III</string>
    <string>JJJ</string>
</array>
```

Thanks guys again for all your help!

Comment: If `items` is `nil`, then your plist is very possibly an `NSDictionary` and not an `NSArray`....

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Turns out the plist was an NSDictionary, so I changed it to an NSArray. Still no dice. Same errors showing up as before.

Comment: Are you sure that the updated file made it into the new bundle?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. How would I check to make sure it did?

Comment: Also, add `NSLog(@"path: %@", path);` to make sure that you found the item that you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I did that and it is finding the file, yet the log is still reading items:(null).

Comment: Open your plist file as a text file and post the text here for us to review.

Comment: Yeah sure I'll add it up top

Comment: Is your post missing the last line or is your file missing it?

Comment: Okay, so regardless of my last comment, this is still a dictionary, with an array in it.  Your top level object needs to be an array, or you need to read it in as a dictionary.  Notice how right under plist it says `<dict>`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your plist is not an array, it is a dictionary. So either you need to change your plist,or you need to read it in as a dictionary instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! That finally solved it. Sorry for making such a rookie error.

Answer (score 0):

@Bryman I've executed your code it is working fine for me. Please once recreate your plist file. As you are saying it contains array so I've tested your code by adding array to a plist file.

Comment: Thanks for the response and trying out my code. I recreated my plist yet it's still giving the EXC_ARITHMETIC error. How do I check and make sure my plist is formatted right? I feel that may be the issue here.

Comment: You can show the plist file in xml format as well can you please post that xml format

Comment: Please once print the array count in the log and is it 0 or not. If it is zero then it is not getting the array from your plist or it may be other than array

Comment: Alright when I print the array count the log states the count is (null), so something is screwy with either the plist itself or the link between the plist and the rest of the program. I will add the plist code up top.

Comment: Solved it by changing up my plist. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Bryman you are using array within a dictionary look at the tag <dict> it specifies that your plist is a dictionary so that's why you are getting that error.

Comment: Yup I just changed that to array and it's working like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your simply not being able to read the plist, just check your plist structure,

```
 NSString *StringsFromPList = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
 NSString *itemPositionPlistLocation = [StringsFromPList stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Words.plist"];
 _myDictionary= [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:itemPositionPlistLocation];
NSArray * items = [_myDictionary objectForKey:@"Root"];
```

your plist should match this structure and be reading from the ROOT key not array
hope it helps :)
dont worry it took me ages to find why i couldnt read mine ><

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Root</key>
    <array>
        <string>Happy</string>
        <string>Rain</string>
    </array>
```